# How can I create multiple bibliographies in the same document using {abntex2} and one .bib?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, multiple-citations, abnt, abntex2

I have been trying [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions%2FCreating_multiple_bibliographies_in_the_same_document#The_chapterbib_package), and I don't know the reason, but none worked here.

config.cls

```latex
\LoadClass[12pt,openright,oneside,a4paper,chapter=TITLE]{abntex2}
\RequirePackage{times}          % Usa Times Roman para texto 
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Seleção de códigos de fonte.
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codificação e conversão automática
\RequirePackage{subcaption}     % Pacote para definição dos subcaptions (ambientes de subfigures)
\RequirePackage{makeidx}        % Cria o índice
\RequirePackage{hyperref}       % Controla a formação do índice
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}    % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo do capítulo
\RequirePackage{graphicx}       % Inclusão de gráficos
\RequirePackage{lastpage}       % Usado pela ficha catalográfica
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{multirow}          
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\RequirePackage{xstring}        % Manipulação de strings
```

general.tex

```latex
\usepackage[bibjustif, abnt-full-initials=yes, abnt-repeated-title-omit=yes, alf]{abntex2cite} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

\input{paper1.tex}

\input{paper2.tex}

\chapter{CONCLUSION}

% I want to see ALL citations from all papers

\bibliographystyle{abntex2-alf} 

\bibliography{referencias.bib}
\end{document}
```

paper1.tex and paper2.tex:

```latex
\chapter{TITLE}

...

\chapter{CONCLUSION}

% I want to see the citation of each paper
\bibliographystyle{abntex2-alf} 

\bibliography{referencias.bib}
```

I want to see something like this:

```
SUMÁRIO

INTRODUCTION . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 11

1 TITLE 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .................... . . . . . . . 12
1.1 sections . ............................................................... . . 15
1.2 References ....................................................................19

2 TITLE 2  . . . ................................................................. 20
2.1 sections . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 20
2.2 References ....................................................................28

3 CONCLUSION . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ...... . ............ 29
REFERENCES . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ........... . . . 30
```